# Mysql 5.7 keeps shutting itself off randomly in a day or two?

Tags: nginx, mysql, wordpress, ubuntu-16.04

I have a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 16.4 machine with Nginx installed. Maybe it's related to Wordpress installation, maybe not. MySQL shuts itself down randomly.

It has a 1GB swap file created. 1GB RAM. Might not be related to memory issue.

Started to happen when I did an `apt-get upgrade` and the upgrade stopped while MySQL was upgrading.

No error log at all.

But here is the log from Ubuntu-

```
(Reading database ... ^M(Reading database ... 5%^M(Reading database ... 
10%^M(Reading database ... 
15%^M(Reading database ... 20%^M(R$
Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-168 (4.4.0-168.197) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 143: /usr/share/mysql- 
common/configure-symlinks: 
No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup 
error from a previous 
failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
```

I found a fix way back by commenting out a line in the MySQL configuration file but forgot which one. That fixed it when same problem encountered. Memory allocation looks fine as far as I am concerned but then again, I am never logged in or monitoring the process when it's shutting down.

Comment: What's the result when invoke: `dpkg -l | grep -i mysql`?

Comment: @NeilWang https://imgur.com/JUHCAEY 
I actually had PHP 7.0 installed and then upgraded to 7.2. Did I need to do anything to hook mysql up with new PHP installation? The issue started to happen after I ran a command to upgrade Ubuntu with apt-get upgrade and got stuck with mysql on the error shown in the question.

Comment: there is nothing related with PHP and MySQL. The reason I would like you to check the dpkg package is the strange error on your log:"mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7". I think your MySQL package is either duplicated or broken.

Comment: Looks to me like an installation issue as well. Export the database, remove MySQL completely, reinstall, import data. I'm not a DB expert though.

Comment: What messages in MySQL log files?

Comment: @RickJames once I restart mysql, it logs the usual startup logs but nothing else whenever it shuts itself down, just empty after the initial logs.

Comment: @NeilWang The duplication might be the case btw. When I tried to update and upgrade Ubuntu, it did the upgrades and informed in a dialogue that the version of MySQL changed and if I would like to keep the current one or add the new one. I selected the keep as is one though, the local copy. Maybe then the duplication happened? Which should not be the case though as I selected to leave as is.

Comment: Was `mysql_upgrade` run?

Comment: @RickJames no. That's where the upgrade stopped. And the issue began.

Comment: Let's focus on what the script `mysql_upgrade` was doing when it stopped.  Note:  I am asking about that script, not the entire apt get.

Comment: @RickJames When I run mysql_upgrade, it runs and shows ok to everything and runs successfully. FYI: apt get stops upgrading at mysql with the error specified on the image attached with the question.

Comment: I think the mysql packages are already inconsistent. The version asked you to keep or not should be the my.cnf configuration file. I think you should took Tim's advice: backup data, purge mysql, install mysql and restore data.

Comment: @NeilWang Ok. I'll do that. Will it affect the PHP or Nginx installation in any way? Just to be safe.

Comment: @RPMcMurphy No, it definitely won't affect other installations